# How to put 3 dropdown select form in a row with bootstrap 4 in cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put 3 drop down select item in the same row, but they end up in the one column in a .cshtml file.

The shorten part of the code is right below (the complete section of code is at the end of the question with the current outcome).

```html
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-5">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-5">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div clas="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-4">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4">
        </div>        
        <div class="form-group col-4">
        </div>        
      </div>
```

The first section, three pieces show up in the same line as expected. (col-2, col-5, col-5).
But the second section, the three select drop down showing up in a column instead of the same row.

```html
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-2">
          <label>Item ID</label>
          <input readonly class="form-control" type="text" value="@pi.ProjectItemId" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-5">
          <label for="ItemName_@(pi.ProjectItemId)">Item Name</label>
          <input id="ItemName_@(pi.ProjectItemId)" class="form-control" type="text" value="@pi.ItemName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-5">
          <label for="ItemDescription_@(pi.ProjectItemId)">Item Description</label>
          <textarea id="ItemDescription_@(pi.ProjectItemId)" class="form-control" type="text" row=3>@(pi.ItemDescription)</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div clas="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-4">
          <label for="ItemTechnology_@(pi.TechId)">Technology:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="ItemTechnology_@(pi.ProjectItemId)">
            @foreach(var tech in @ViewBag.ListOfTechnologies)
            {
              @if(@pi.TechId == @tech.TechId)
              {
               <option value=@(tech.TechId) selected>@(tech.TechId)</option>
              }
              else 
              {
                <option value=@(tech.TechId)>@(tech.TechId)</option>
              }
            }
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4">
          <label for="MainApplication_@(pi.ProjectItemId)">Main Application:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="MainApplication_@(pi.ProjectItemId)">
            @foreach(var app in @ViewBag.ListOfApplications)
            {
              @if(@pi.MainApplicationId == @app.ApplicationId)
              {
                <option value=@(app.ApplicationId) selected>@(app.ApplicationId)</option>
              }
              else
              {
                <option value=@(app.ApplicationId)>@(app.ApplicationId)</option>
              }
            }
          </select>
        </div>        
        <div class="form-group col-4">
          <label for="SecondaryApplication_@(pi.ProjectItemId)">Secondary Application:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="SecondaryApplication_@(pi.ProjectItemId)">
            @foreach(var app in @ViewBag.ListOfApplications)
            {
              @if(@pi.SecondaryApplicationId == @app.ApplicationId)
              {
                <option value=@(app.ApplicationId) selected>@(app.ApplicationId)</option>
              }
              else
              {
                <option value=@(app.ApplicationId)>@(app.ApplicationId)</option>
              }
              if (@pi.SecondaryApplicationId == null)
              {
                <option value=0>No secondary application was chosen.</option>
              }
            }
          </select>
        </div>        
      </div>
```

[image: Picture of the outcome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was perfect.  You have made a spelling mistake for the `class` in second row. Instead of `class`, you have mentioned it as `clas`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-2"> 1
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-5"> 2
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-5">
    3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-4">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-4">
    6
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes it happens :). Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong classes, you should use col-md-2 or son on.

Look at the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your code like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div clas="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```